# EdgeRenderingFunction and VertexRenderingFunction help

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm trying to construct a LayeredGraphPlot where some nodes connect to other nodes, like a tree. I would like to have the freedom to choose the thickness, color, presence or absence of labeling of each edge.

I would also like to have the freedom to display some vertex names and display some vertices as just "dots". I can't seem to understand how EdgeRenderingFunction and VertexRenderingFunction enable me to do this.

I am new to mathematica. I've clicked on more information on Wolfram help page but it appears to have a vague description  and not precise syntax, followed by some cute but unhelpful (to me) examples (As compared to matlab at mathworks where the help provides precise syntax.. at least in my mind).
I have looked up about 10 mathematics books (Smith and Blachman, mathematica demystified.. etc etc) but they all seem to cover the function superficially with one or two examples and not provide the most general syntax.

Can someone help with this and I would also appreciate tips on how to learn mathematica? I'm a smart guy and I should not have so much trouble learning how to use commands.

LayeredGraphPlot[{1->2,1->3,2->4,3->5,3->6}]

So for example, I'd like to:

1. Suppress all the vertex names except vertices 4,5 and 6.
2. Color as blue and thick the edges from 3->6, 2->4 and 1->3
3. All the other edges to be red and thin

Comment: I think your inexperience with Mathematica is what's holding you up here. The help files are great when you're familiar with the system, but admittedly they don't provide much that helps get a beginner up to speed quickly; the only reliable way I've found to get familiar with Mathematica is to use it as much as possible. I'll see if I can write something up when I get time.

Comment: You did open the "More Information" box right below the syntax section, did you? Just checkin'

Comment: Sjoerd: I did look up "MoreInfo" and then looked up the syntax on functions and then didn't find a function definition that looked anything like they used in the LayeredG.. examples.

Comment: Thanks a lot Belisarius!!! I did look up GraphPlot but that sent me to EdgeRenderingfunc and then I could not understand how to define the EdgeRendering function.. I looked up functions in mathematica and eventually got lost. Now with your code, there is plenty of information that I can play around and try other specifications. I definitely do appreciate the power of Mathematica and I do see myself getting competent with mathematica coding. anyway.. thanks a lot for your help! I really appreciate it!

Comment: Similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897479/creating-a-graph-with-edges-of-different-colours-in-mathematica

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`VertexRenderingFunction` and `EdgeRenderingFunction` allow you to take explicit control over the way that vertices and edges are drawn in the graph.  Both functions are expected to return a symbolic graphics directive (or list of such directives) that is valid for the [Graphics](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Graphics.html) command.

Let's start with `VertexRenderingFunction`.  We shall define a new function called `drawVertex`.  A `VertexRenderingFunction` is called with two arguments: the position of the vertex (as an X/Y co-ordinate pair) and the name of the vertex.

```
drawVertex[position_, vertex:(4 | 5 | 6)] :=
  Inset[Framed[vertex, Background -> LightMagenta], position]

drawVertex[position_, _] :=
  {PointSize[Medium], Blue, Point[position]}
```

Two definitions are provided for `drawVertex`.  The first is only applicable to the vertices `4` or `5` or `6`.  It draws those vertices as framed labels.  The second definition is applicable to all other vertices and draws simple blue points.

Now for an `EdgeRenderingFunction` named `drawEdge`.  The function will be passed three arguments: the endpoints of the edge, a list of the source and target vertices of the edge, and the label for the edge (if any).  In our case, all edges will be drawn as arrows but the colour and thickness will vary depending upon the edge.  The helper function `edgeStyle` is introduced to capture those differences:

```
drawEdge[ends_, fromTo_, label_] :=
  Join[edgeStyle[fromTo], {Arrowheads[{{Automatic, 0.5}}], Arrow[ends]}]

edgeStyle[{3, 6} | {2, 4} | {1, 3}] :=
  {Blue, Thick}

edgeStyle[_] :=
  {Red, Thin}
```

With these definitions in place, we can now use them in conjunction with `LayeredGraphPlot` to produce a customized diagram:

```
LayeredGraphPlot[{1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 2 -> 4, 3 -> 5, 3 -> 6},
  VertexRenderingFunction -> drawVertex, EdgeRenderingFunction -> drawEdge ]
```

[image: layered graph]

Comment: Oh man! (or woman)... Thanks a lot! That went a long way in clearing the picture for me. Thanks WReach!

Comment: Thanks again Wreach! Now I get the picture of how to create my own functions. I think this will help me in many many other parts. Now the More Info section is making more sense. I really appreciate your help. Thanks!

Comment: Hi WReach, I mimicked your code and produced something close to what I wanted to produce and I posted it as an answer because I didn't know how to post it in the comment. Thanks for your help. Your detailed example really helped me understand the structure to some extent. Thx

Answer (score 3):

```
LayeredGraphPlot[
 {1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 2 -> 4, 3 -> 5, 3 -> 6}, 
 VertexRenderingFunction -> 
    (If[Intersection[{4, 5, 6}, {#2}] != {},
          {White, EdgeForm[Black], Disk[#, .1], Black, Text[#2, #1]}, 
          {PointSize[Large], Point[#1]}] &),
 EdgeRenderingFunction ->
    (If[Intersection[{{3, 6}, {2, 4}, {1, 3}}, {#2}] != {}, 
          {Blue, Thick, Line[#1]}, 
          {Red, Line[#1]}] &)
 ]
```

[image]

Mathematica syntax is daunting at first glance. Almost every powerful tool is.
I think the short snippets provided here in StackOverflow as answers to new Mma users are a good starting point for the first steps. Please note that there are also advanced and much more difficult questions posted.

Mathematica is not intended for the casual user. If you are not planning to invest some time in learning and getting accustomed, I suggest trying another tool.

Finally, the `LayeredGraphPlot[]` function is not covered in depth in the help system, simply because it is a cousin of `GraphPlot[]`, whose help page is the root for all Graph...[] family help searches.

Answer (score 0):

I mimicked your code and managed to produce something very close to what I actually wanted. Thanks a lot for your help!

[image]

```
    {drawVertex[position_, 
    vertex : (1111 | 1112 | 1121 | 1122 | 1211 | 1212 | 1221 | 1222)] :=
    Inset[Framed[
    Text[If[vertex == 1111, "80,70", 
    If[vertex == 1112, "50,60", 
    If[vertex == 1121, "105,50", If[vertex == 1122, "70,55",
    If[vertex == 1211, "70,40", 
    If[vertex == 1212, "90,50", 
    If[vertex == 1221, "85,60", "40,50"]]]]]]]], 
    Background -> White], position]
    drawVertex[position_, _] := {PointSize[Medium], Blue, Point[position]}
    drawEdge[ends_, fromTo_, 
    label_] := {Join[
    edgeStyle[fromTo], {Arrowheads[{{Automatic, 1}}], Arrow[ends]}], 
    Text[label, Mean[ends]]}

    edgeStyle[{1, 11} | {11, 111} | {111, 1111}] := {Blue, Thick}

    edgeStyle[_] := {Red, Thin}
    LayeredGraphPlot[{{1 -> 11, "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\"C\", 
    RowBox[{\"1\", \"L\"}]]\)"}, {1 -> 12, "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\"C\", 
    RowBox[{\"1\", \"R\"}]]\)"}, {11 -> 111, 
    "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\"H\", \"L\"]\)"}, {11 -> 112, 
    "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\"H\", \"H\"]\)"}, {12 -> 121, 
    "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\"H\", \"L\"]\)"}, {12 -> 122, 
    "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\"H\", \"H\"]\)"}, {111 -> 1111, 
    "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\"C\", 
    RowBox[{\"0\", \"L\"}]]\)"}, {111 -> 1112, "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\"C\", 
    RowBox[{\"0\", \"H\"}]]\)"}, {112 -> 1121, "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\"C\", 
    RowBox[{\"0\", \"L\"}]]\)"}, {112 -> 1122, "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\"C\",  
    RowBox[{\"0\", \"H\"}]]\)"}, {121 -> 1211, "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\"C\", 
    RowBox[{\"0\", \"L\"}]]\)"}, {121 -> 1212, "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\"C\", 
    RowBox[{\"0\", \"H\"}]]\)"}, {122 -> 1221, "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\"C\", 
    RowBox[{\"0\", \"L\"}]]\)"}, {122 -> 1222, "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\"C\", 
    RowBox[{\"0\", \"H\"}]]\)"}}, EdgeRenderingFunction -> drawEdge, 
    VertexRenderingFunction -> drawVertex]}
```